# Hiding Twitter profile pics in Tweetdeck

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

Where in Tweetdeck is the option of not displaying people's profile pics and just displaying their name?

Or should I look at another Twitter client for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick search and couldn't find an application on any platform that promotes that as a feature or as a TweetDeck option. So then I decided to take a crack at modifying a Windows based open source twitter client, and introduce the feature. As of 6th January this feature is in the public application.

## Halfwit

You can get it here [madprops.org/halfwit/](http://madprops.org/halfwit/) go down to the '*Where do I get it?*' section.

It's only for Windows, so if you're on another platform, happy hunting.

#### Screen Shots

Go to options:

[image]

Pull the *Profile Picture Size* slider all the way to the left.

[image]

There you go, no images just text.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 2: This is now a Chrome Extension, [get it here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/utweetdeck/mamdemofgfmcdefkmolnnenmhmecpgbo).

*original post below*

Bit of a flimsy front-end hack, but you can paste the following javascript in the browser console and remove the profile pictures.  Code [on github also.](https://github.com/DeBraid/js-snippets/blob/master/cleaner-tweetdeck.js)

```
(function(){
    $(".tweet-avatar.avatar.pull-right").remove();
    $(".tweet").css({ "padding-left" : "5px" });
})();
```

EDIT: the code above will remove profile pics, but new tweets are loaded with a pic.

Below code automatically re-runs the `remove()` snippet above when new tweets enter the feed:

```
var s_ajaxListener = new Object();
s_ajaxListener.tempOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
s_ajaxListener.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

s_ajaxListener.callback = function() {
    // runs on XHR events
    // to remove profile pics
    $(".tweet-avatar.avatar.pull-right").remove();
    $(".tweet").css({ "padding-left": "5px" });
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(a, b) {
    if (!a) var a = '';
    if (!b) var b = '';
    s_ajaxListener.tempOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    s_ajaxListener.method = a;
    s_ajaxListener.url = b;
    if (a.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        s_ajaxListener.data = b.split('?');
        s_ajaxListener.data = s_ajaxListener.data[1];
    }
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(a, b) {
    if (!a) var a = '';
    if (!b) var b = '';
    s_ajaxListener.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
    if (s_ajaxListener.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') s_ajaxListener.data = a;
    s_ajaxListener.callback();
}
```